# How to disable anonymous checkout with apache svn server

Tags: apache, svn

I build a SVN server with apache. It work fine.

I don't want to anonymous could checkout, so I set httpd like

```
<location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath Off
    SVNParentPath C:/SVN/
    Satisfy All
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Dir"
    AuthUserFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\svn-auth-conf.txt"
    AuthzSVNAccessFile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\svn-acl-conf.txt"
    Require valid-user
</location>
```

but I still can checkout by commnd line like

```
svn co http://repos test
```

without any username and password

How can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may have stored credentials for this URL
2. Remove `Satisfy` - read ["Blanket access control"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.blanket) in SVN Book with sample

   `AuthName ...`
   `AuthType ...`
   `AuthUserFile ...` 
   `Require valid-user`

Comment: It's only block user on Browser. I don't want to guest who can checkout it. But everyone can check it when use command line.

Comment: @AdolphDrizzt - you are wrong! **Read docs** and test - I know topic and tested it on my server. Create repo, for which you haven't stored credentials and *with `Require` only* you'll get auth-request on `svn co`.

Comment: It's my fault. You're right. After test I cannot access to any file no matter browser or command line. 401 failed. I will test more. Thank your help.